# is there a relation between the trace of a 3x3 real, symmetric, positive definite matrix and the trace of its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, invariant-theory

Let $\mathbb{M}^{3\times3}$ denote the set of real, symmetric, and positive definite $3\times3$ matrices.

Given $A \in \mathbb{M}^{3\times3}$ with the property $\det A=1$.

In my engineering application, I observed that $\mathrm{tr} A$ and $\mathrm{tr} A^{-1}$ are somehow related; $\mathrm{tr}$ denotes the trace. In particular, if I plot $\mathrm{tr} A$ and $\mathrm{tr} A^{-1}$ in a 2d scatter plot, the tuples $\{\mathrm{tr} A, \mathrm{tr} A^{-1} \}$ are located close to the diagonal line. I know that $\mathrm{tr} A \geq 3$ and $\mathrm{tr} A^{-1} \geq 3$.

I was wondering if there is maybe a mathematical relation between these two quantities, that could explains the relation. Admittedly, I do not have enough mathematical background to derive a possible relation. I also do not know if the information that I provided are enough to address this problem -- if not, please let me know.

Any help or ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: If $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \lambda_3 > 0$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $\operatorname{tr}(A) = \sum_i \lambda_i$, $\operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}) = \sum_i \frac{1}{\lambda_i}$ and $1 = \operatorname{det}(A) = \prod_i \lambda_i$.

Comment: Does this imply a kind if correlation?

Comment: Well, first $\operatorname{tr}(A), \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1})\ge 3$ because of the inequality of arithmetic and geometric means.  Second, you can choose any two of the three eigenvalues as any positive numbers and the third is determined by the condition $\operatorname{det}(A)=1$.  If you choose $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 > 0$ then $\lambda_3 = \frac{1}{\lambda_1 \lambda_2}$ and a calculation shows that $\operatorname{tr}(A) - \operatorname{tr}(A^{-1}) = (1-\frac{1}{\lambda_1})(1-\frac{1}{\lambda_2}) - (1-\lambda_1)(1-\lambda_2)$, so if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are close to $1$ this is nearly $0$.

Comment: So the correlation is expected only if the eigenvalues are close to one?

Comment: It's not "only if".  There other cases for example if $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ are reciprocals, the difference also evaluates to zero.  OTOH you can choose $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ so that the difference goes to $+\infty$ or $-\infty$ as you like.

Comment: You can try to plot the surface  $z={\frac { \left( x-1 \right)  \left( y-1 \right)  \left( xy-1 \right) }
{xy}}
$ and see what you get.

Comment: @JohnDoe You can write this as an answer if you want